# External Monitor Flickering when Chrome is running

Tags: display, google-chrome, displayport

I have a new macbook, v 10.14.3. It is connected to two external monitors --  both of them DELL which are connected via a DELL docking station using mini Displayport cables which came with them.

My monitor is blickering sporadically and I am mostly certain that it only happens when I use Chrome browser (in particular when I open a new tab or load a new webpage). But on the other hand both monitors including the one where browser window is not launched are flickering.

Any way to solve this? I did find a [link](http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/04/fix-flickering-screen-external-display-mac/) suggesting resetting SMC -- but did not try it out as I could not make any sense why such an act would resolve it if it happens only for Chrome

Comment: So try resetting the smc...

Comment: just did that :-) Waiting for the results (observe couple of hours)

Comment: Hope it works, it may be just because of something Chrome calls that others don't...

Comment: looks better now.

Comment: If that works then add an answer ("Based on this link I reset the smc... ...") or update your question as that will help others...

Comment: somehow it happens once in a while again..both monitors completely goes black when that happens..I am beginning to suspect whether sites with flash content are the ones causing problem. Will update here if I have something more interesting

Comment: I disabled "hardware acceleration" in chrome setting as suggested elsewhere. Will update here if it changed anything for better

Comment: Exactly same problem for me. Extended monitors are flickering while using chrome. Still can't find a solution! I didn't expect to see someone else with similar experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reset **System Management Controller** as suggested [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/04/fix-flickering-screen-external-display-mac/).
(for macbook touchbar, make sure that you really press the power button, not just touch it).

But this did not seem to help as problems reoccured. What seem to have helped now is disabling hardware accelerations for Chrome browser. Go to chrome://settings and disable it and that could solve the problem